# postioning: absolute and relative problems

Tags: css, css-position

I am trying to set a heading within a WP plugin form with a class of .wpcf7-form. Within the CSS I have the position to relative on the form and the heading to absolute but for some reason the heading ends at the bottom of the page. Any suggestions?

WP template

```
<h3 class="contact-heading">Get in Touch</h3>

<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="278" title="Contact form 1"]' ); ?>
```

CSS

```
h3.contact-heading{color:  #0C0; font: 2.0em Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight: 
normal;letter-spacing: 5px; text-transform:uppercase; position: absolute;}

.wpcf7-form {background-color:#909673; border:none; color:#333; font:1.2em  
Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; padding:50px 0px 30px 20px; position:relative; width:450px;}
.wcf7_name {height:25px; width:225px;}
.wcf7_email {height:25px; width:225px;}
.wcf7_subject {height:25px; width:225px;}
.wpcf7-captcha-captcha-803 {border: 2px dashed #333;}
.text-field {height:25px; width:75px;}
.wcf7_msg {height:200px; width:425px;}
.wpcf7-submit{font: 1.0em Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; padding:5px 10px; 
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #999;}
```

I have tried putting the ".wpcf7-form" at the beginning of the h3 selector but it changes all of the css.

Comment: have you tried something as simple as giving it a height

Comment: adding height to the form pushes it off the page

Comment: Be useful if we could see the html output as well. Try adding top:0; left:0; to the header style ?

Comment: A working example would be helpful. if the `h3` has a class of `.wpcf7-form` then try `h3.wpcf7 {...}`

Comment: html is being generated by the plugin, and the site is being run locally. Here is a link to the code WP is outputting: http://jsfiddle.net/NGhv4/

Comment: Added an answer below. That will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `top` and `left` properties.

```
h3.contact-heading{
    color:  #0C0; 
    font: 2.0em Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 5px; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /* ADD THIS */
    left: 0; /* ADD THIS*/
}
```

**EDIT

Had a look at your jsFiddle example.
You need to add a `z-index` property to your `h3`.

```
h3.contact-heading{
    ...
    z-index: 100;      
}
```

Comment: Did it work for you on the jfiddle? It didn't work for me on my code.

Comment: Yeah, it did. Look here: [http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/NGhv4/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/NGhv4/1/)